# Doing an action exactly once

Tags: java, android

I`m trying to add tracking events to my android app using Mixpanel (it simply tracks what actions the user is doing in an application), and I want to add an event called "Application Started". 
The question is, where should I track the event of the app starting without having it repeated. **Is there a method or a function call in the life cycle that executes when the app first starts and only once ?**

Comment: i would suggest you to save ur state in shared pref android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in onCreate() of your application class.. it will be done only once when app gets started...

Comment: In the Application class? Should i find a class called Application? or is that supposed to be my main activity class ?

Comment: No, application class is different from activities.. For an application, there can be only on application class.. And that you declare in the manifest file.. Typically like this

Answer (score 1):

No, application class is different from activities.. For an application, there can be only on application class.. And that you declare in the manifest file.. Typically like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@override
onCreate()
{
// Do your task here..
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in as a preference value:

```
SharedPreferences setting = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean firstStart = setting.getBoolean("firstStart",true);
if(firstStart == true) {
    //do work first time

    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = setting.edit();
    edit.putBoolean("firstStart", false);
    edit.commit();
}
```

Comment: But doesn't this mean that the value false will persist even after the app is closed and started again? so it will always be false after the first start ?

Comment: The preference values are persistent because they're stored in an external xml file. Next time when you start the app, the values will persist.

Comment: Yes but i dont want the value to persist past the application life time. So that when the user next opens the application, a new call to the Track_Event() function is called.

Comment: If you don't want the value to persist after you close the application then you just do it in `onCreate()` method only.